# Spring Cloud Data Flow Kubernetes Deployment fails for external database - Cannot load driver class: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver

Tags: mysql, kubernetes-helm, minikube, spring-cloud-dataflow

I am following the developer guide to [deploy SCDF to a minikube cluster](https://dataflow.spring.io/docs/installation/kubernetes/) on my local machine. Used the [helm chart approach](https://dataflow.spring.io/docs/installation/kubernetes/helm/). Was able to get it working with the defaults.  The default deploys a mariadb in the cluster. I wanted to change it to use an external mysql db that is running in a docker container in my machine (outside the cluster). Followed the recommendations to change the values.yaml to enable the external DB and attributes for external DB connection (URI, dbname, user/pwd etc.).

Then deployed using "helm install my-release -f values.yaml bitnami/spring-cloud-dataflow"

The SCDF pod (& skipper pod) errors out because it can't find the mysql jdbc driver. kubectl logs on the pods show the following error: "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"

How do I include the mysql jdbc driver in the image for SCDF that gets deployed (or resolve this problem). I read SCDF already includes the drivers for std databases (true ?). New to helm/k8s so apologies if solution is obvious... Other posts on similar error all talk about including this in the pom.xml . But this is not a dependency issue with my (task) app but SCDF itself.

thanks

-------------------- more detail on the exception stack ---------------
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:657)
...

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I just need to specify the mariadb jdbc driver in the values.yaml file for mysql as well. That got past the load class error.

But still would like to know how to prevent class load error for a different driver specified when SCDF is deployed to k8s via the helm chart.